# Como escrever entradas do usuário em arquivos python?

Tags: python

Sou iniciante em python e estou fazendo um exercício que pede que eu crie um banco de dados simples em um arquivo .txt que possibilite ao usuário cadastrar e consultar produtos e seus valores em reais, sem a necessidade de acessar o arquivo (abrir, mas não mostrar em tela). Segue meu código:

```
import os
try:
    op = open('C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/database.txt','a')
except:
    op = open('C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/database.txt', 'w')
dict = {}
while True:
    menu = int(input("Type 1 to register,2 to consult or 3 to remove: "))
    if menu == 1:
        #cadastrar produtos
        prod_cad = str(input("Type the product name: ")
        if [dict.has_key(prod_cad)]:
            print("This product is already registered.")
        else:
            val = float(input(" Type the price of product: "))
            op.write(dict[prod_cad]=val",")
```

Minha dúvida está justamente nessa  última parte que grava o nome e o valor do produto no arquivo. Não faço ideia de como mandar esses valores para o arquivo e organizar de modo que cada tupla 'produto': valor(int) seja separada por vírgula e se mantenha acessível para posterior consulta do usuário. Eu sei que não posso mandar escrever assim:
    `op.write(dict['prod_cad']='val')` porque eu estaria mandando o nome da variável e não o valor. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar!

Answer (score 3):

Tente rodar seu código e, provavelmente, não conseguirá, tem alguns erros de sintaxe. Tente rodar a versão abaixo:

```
import os
f = open("products.txt", "w")
dict = {}
while True:
    pd = input('Type the product name ("End" for quit)')
    if pd.lower()=='end':
        f.close()
        break
    if pd in dict:
        print ('This product is already registered')
    else:
        pr = float(input(" Type the price of product: ")) 
        s = pd+','+str(pr)+'\n'
        dict[pd] = pr
        f.write(s)
```

Digamos que vc entre com os valores:

```
Productname    Price:
p1             10  
p2             20 
p3             30
End
```

Se vc mandar listar o arquivo (`type` no windows, `cat` no linux) verá o seguinte:

```
$ cat products.txt
p1,10.0
p2,20.0
p3,30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Creio que nesse caso você pode usar o `.format`:

```
produto = ("{} = {}").format(dict[prod_cad], val)
op.write(produto)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples